How do I control the “back buffer” size for an HTML video element?
For example, I have a 30 second video playing. The browser manages a forward buffer for the video, which allows me to click the play head forward in time to jump to a point without waiting for buffering. There’s also a back buffer, which allows me to jump back in time without rebuffering.
The problem is the back buffer is much much smaller than the forward buffer, so it almost always rebuffers. How can I control the size of the back buffer?
